# How to replace os disk with attached data disk on azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disk

I attached a new vhd file to my virtual machine but I could not find a way to boot that machine with this disk. How can I boot my virtual machine with newly attached data disk?

Edit: I found the way of creating of vm from captured vm image. It is preformed on VM Images section. Now my problem is that when I transfer the captured page blobs from one azure account to another account they appear on storage account section but not on VM Images section. Hence I am not able to create VM from transferred images. How can I make this blobs appear on VM Image or is there a way to transfer VM Image disk directly to the section of VM Images of another azure account by using azure-cli?

I would like to create OS Disk from a vhd file. In microsoft documents [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-create-upload-vhd/) as it mentioned there is a command `azure vm image create` in my azure-cli there is no such command. I could not find a way to make an OS Disk from my stored vhd files.

**Solved**: Using [classic portal of Azure](https://manage.windowsazure.com) it is easy to create vm images or os disks and creating vms from these images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-attach-disk/) to get disk up and running, check the section ***'Initialize the disk'***.

Source : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-attach-disk/

Comment: I have ubuntu machine and I don't understand if this is so complex. Isn't there any way to restore a virtual machine with captured image of that virtual machine?

Comment: Just use powershell then https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495298.aspx

Comment: Feel free to upvote and make it as the answer @mustafa.yavuz .

Comment: Hi S A, I thought choosing it as answer but it is actually not exact solution. Problem was that I thought classic portal of azure does not exist anymore where some of the functions exist there and does not exist on new portal. Without powershell all of the tasks I stated above can be solve easily on classic portal.

Comment: @mustafa.yavuz but in the link it does direct you to do in the old portal.

Comment: @S A You are right. It is not accessible and it seems it is related to subscription you have on azure. Here is an argumentation on it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/10287573-i-can-t-access-old-portal-manage-windowsazure-red